# How to decompile a plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, plugins, server, minecraft, bukkit

I have recently started learning to develop minecraft plugins and heard a good way to learn is to decompile other plugins and then learn what the code inside them does but i looked it up and could not find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to decompile plugins, I would recommend using a program called [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten/releases). You can open up jar files and see whats inside and see the code. Keep in mind, some plugins may be obfuscated and decompiling some plugins may be against the developer's TOS. If you are in the clear, you can open up a jar file in Luyten by dragging the file onto the window and you can have a look at the code there. But if you would like to edit the code in something like eclipse, you can click the 'File' tab up the top right and click 'Save All'. Then extract all the files inside the zip file and then open up the project in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Like @exro mentioned before, you should use [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten/releases) to decompile the code first and be aware of the developer's *terms of service and the copyright licensing of the code* as sometimes attempts to re-create/decompile the code will be considered a violation of their copyright and could get you into  legal issues.

@exro has done quite a good job explaining how to do it on [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten/releases), though I'd personally like to recommend that you check out github.com and have a look at some of these projects.

1. https://github.com/ElevatedDev/Frequency

> Frequency is a Spigot open-sourced Anti-Cheat made by a few developers and the licensing should enable you to re-create the code in Eclipse without any legal difficulties though this should not be considered legal advice (Please also note that Frequency is created in IntelliJ and Maven so I would recommend that you either learn how to use those tools or just be aware of what they are).

2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wysn_pFhcmE&list=PLdnyVeMcpY79UFZFfqwaXF2GUGc0v3YyG

> This is a beginner-friendly Bukkit/Java coding course which will get you over the first few projects you'll do.